Delete a range of rows based of three criteria
I have an excel file with large amount of rows (around 20k) related to different cases.
Each case is separated with "--------". My target is to delete every row between the separators when a keyword is find. Keywords appear repeatedly.
This is what I was able (with help of course) to produce:
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
    Set Revision = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revision")
    lastRow = GetLastRow(Revision.Cells)
    Set RngEntire = Revision.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Trim(Revision.Cells(i, 1).Value), "*8951MFS3*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            startRow = i

            If startRow > 0 And endRow > startRow Then
                Revision.Range(Revision.Cells(startRow + 1, 1), Revision.Cells(endRow - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
                startRow = i
                endRow = i
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(1, Trim(Revision.Cells(i, 1).Value), "*----------*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            endRow = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

I don't know why the code is not working, no errors present :(
For the GetLastRow I have a function.
Thanks in advance for any support!
Best wishes!

You don't need * in InStr function.

In other words, I I would say that you need to delete the rows starting with the one containing in A:A "8951MFS3" up to the one containing "----------" in A:A (included), would it be a correct understanding of what you need?

Also "not working" does not convey any information - always be explicit in describing what happens. It's also a good idea to provide a set of data that produces the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Finally - there are many ways to get the last row and not all of them work if the data is  not contiguous

Removing the * helped! thanks a lot! Any ideas how to delete multiple row between separators if a keyword is found?

You did not answer my above clarification question. Please, test the code I posted, supposing that my understanding is correct...

Please, try the next adapted code. If counts the rows between the markers and deletes al the range at once. This is the part consuming more time...
Sub testDeleteRangesBetweenMarkers()
    Dim Revision As Worksheet, RngEntire As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, startRow As Long, endRow As Long
    Set Revision = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revision")
    lastRow = Revision.Range("A" & Revision.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set RngEntire = Revision.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'to make the code faster, for a big range
     For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Trim(Revision.cells(i, 1).value), "8951MFS3", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            startRow = i: endRow = i
            
            'memorize the rows to be delete limits and make the deletion at once:
            Do
                If i = 0 then Exit Do 'Just in case, if the second marker is not found...
                If InStr(1, Trim(Revision.cells(startRow, 1).value), "----------", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Revision.rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).EntireRow.Delete
                    i = startRow: Exit Do
                Else
                    startRow = startRow - 1
                End If
            Loop
        End If
     Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

The above code could be optimized to use Union ranges, but if a lot of ranges should be included in this range, the code speed will decrease considerable...
I still cannot understand which is the third criteria...
Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Let assume that this is the input:
The first and last row must be the separators



XXXXXXX
A
B




1
----------------------



2
a



3
q



4
w



5
e



6
r



7
t



8
8951MFS3



9
k



10
----------------------



11
a



12
s



13
d



14
----------------------



15
f



16
g



17
rt



18
8951MFS3



19
d



20
s



21
----------------------




Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
    Set Revision = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revision")
    lastRow = Revision.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngEntire = Revision.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    range_active = False
    endRow = 0
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Trim(Revision.Cells(i, 1).Value), "----------", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If endRow = 0 Then
              endRow = i
            Else
              startRow = i
            End If
            If endRow > startRow And range_active Then
                Revision.Range(Revision.Cells(startRow + 1, 1), Revision.Cells(endRow - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
                endRow = i
                startRow = 0
                range_active = False
            ElseIf startRow <> 0 And Not range_active Then
                endRow = i
                startRow = 0
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(1, Trim(Revision.Cells(i, 1).Value), "8951MFS3", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            range_active = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

